# Scheme Lexical Parser

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

New to scheme and currently working on a lexical analyzer. Below is my code and I am getting the error 
map: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: #
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
   #

```
#lang racket

(define tokens '((dog noun)
                 (cat noun)
                 (chases verb)
                 (the article)))

(define (getToken word)
  (cadr (assq word tokens)))

(define ttw (lambda (l)
   (map getToken l)))

(define (parse-sentence list)
  (article list))


(define (article list)
   (if (eq? (car list) 'article)
        (begin
          (display "Article: ")
          (display (car list))
          (noun (cdr list))
         )
        (begin
          (display "Not an Article!!!")
          (display (car list)))
       ))

(define (noun list)
   (if (eq? (car list) 'noun)
        (begin
          (display "Noun:")
          (display (car list))
          (noun (cdr list))
          )
        "Not a noun!!!")
       )

(begin
  (display "Enter a Sentance in (): ")
  (let ((input (read)))
        (ttw (parse-sentence input))))
```

My input is (the dog chases the cat)

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Running the program, I see that DrRacket colors this expression red:

```
(map getToken l)
```

which is part of the function

```
(define ttw (lambda (l)
   (map getToken l)))
```

and since the error is

```
map: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: #<void>
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
```

we now know that `ttw` is called with `void` as input and not a list as expected.

Where is `ttw` called? Clicking the "Check Syntax" icon (the check mark with the magnifying glass) and then hovering the mouse over `ttw` shows all uses.

The only use is in:

```
(ttw (parse-sentence input))
```

This means that `parse-sentence` returned `void`. Let's see the definition of `parse-sentence`:

```
(define (parse-sentence list)
   (article list))
```

Okay, so the error must be in `article`:

```
(define (article list)
   (if (eq? (car list) 'article)
        (begin
          (display "Article: ")
          (display (car list))
          (noun (cdr list))               
         )
        (begin
          (display "Not an Article!!!")
          (display (car list)))
       ))
```

And here we see this:

```
 (if ...
     ...
     (begin 
          (display "Not an Article!!!")
          (display (car list))))
```

The construct `begin` returns the value of the last expression. Here `(display ...)` returns `void`.

Checking the output, we see right before the error message:

```
Not an Article!!!the
```

So the problem is that `article` returns something other than a list.

However since you have found an error, I suggest you look into the function `error`.  Something like:  `(error 'article (~a "Not an article, got: " (car list))`. If you use `error` DrRacket will directly show you that an error has been found in `article`.